# Is it possible to repeat a wildcard in regex?

Tags: regular-expressions

`.{5}` would match any string of 5 symbols (excluding newline). Suppose I wanted to define "a 5-character repetition of a single character."

The immediate way that comes to mind is `(.)\1{4}`, but this relies on a back reference.

Using a subset of regex which is dependent only on `|,(),*,concat` any regex expression of pattern size `M` and search string size `N` can be solved with a  means an `M`-size NFA in `O(NM)` time.

Backreferences, unlike `+, {n}, etc.` are not derivable from the restricted regex tools above, and result in exponential times.

Is it possible to replicate the desired pattern in the non-exponential-time subset of regex (without using exponential* size)? **If not, then why (how can we prove so)?**

*one could go factorial in size by brute-forcing in this case.

Comment: the pattern `.{r5}` would expand into a `5*n` NFA where n is the size of the alphabet, it would quickly get out of hand

Comment: @ratchetfreak I suspected that was the case (see my note*). How can you prove that that is the case?

Comment: Without being able to refer to a previous element in an expression, you can't match a group of the same element without brute forcing it.

Comment: `\1` is not backtracking but backrefrencing. You can make it without backtracking: `(.)\1{10}` on string `aaaaaaaaaaa` takes 3 steps, however `(.)(?1){10}` takes 22 steps to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backreferences you can accept non-regular languages such as the language of squares $ww$, which is accepted by `(.*)\1`. This language cannot be represented as a non-extended regular expression at all.

Comment: Why not? (It certainly makes intuitive sense, but that's not enough...)

Comment: That's a standard exercise. You can prove it using the pumping lemma or using Myhill–Nerode.